# I keep only getting these compiling answers in 3 methods. JAVA

Tags: java, printwriter

Please ignore the sloppy coding. I'm pretty new to java and I am trying to do this project for school. I can't find what is causing this error for

```
DeCrossDiscipline.java:455: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
         PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);
                                  ^
DeCrossDiscipline.java:533: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
         PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);
                                  ^
DeCrossDiscipline.java:623: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
         PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);
                                  ^
3 errors
```

This is the program I am getting the errors in. Please help. I feel like i just need another pair of eyes to spot the problem for me.
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

```
public class DeCrossDiscipline
{
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
      {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      int deSelection;
      int method;
      int method2;
      int method3;
      blanklines();

      System.out.println("\tDifferential Equation Cross Discipline Project");

      System.out.println();

      demenu();
      deSelection = keyboard.nextInt();

      if (deSelection<1)
         {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("That is not a choice. Please try again.\n");
            demenu();
            deSelection = keyboard.nextInt();
           }

      if (deSelection>3)
         {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("That is not a choice. Please try again.\n");
            demenu();
            deSelection = keyboard.nextInt();
           }


      if (deSelection==1)
         {menu1();
          method=keyboard.nextInt();
          if (method<1)
          { 
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Not a valid choice!");
            menu1();
            method=keyboard.nextInt();
           }
           if (method>2)
          { 
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Not a valid choice!");
            menu1();
            method=keyboard.nextInt();
           }

           if (method==1)
           {rungeKutta1();
           }
           if (method==2)
           {euler1();
           }
          }
      if (deSelection==2)
         {menu2();
          method2=keyboard.nextInt();
           if (method2<1)
          { 
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Not a valid choice!");
            menu2();
            method2=keyboard.nextInt();
           }
           if (method2>2)
          { 
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Not a valid choice!");
            menu2();
            method2=keyboard.nextInt();
           }
           if (method2==1)
           {rungeKutta2();
           }
           if (method2==2)
           {euler2();
           }
           }
       if (deSelection==3)
         {menu3();
          method3=keyboard.nextInt();
          if (method3<1)
          { 
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Not a valid choice!");
            menu3();
            method3=keyboard.nextInt();
           }
           if (method3>2)
          { 
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Not a valid choice!");
            menu3();
            method3=keyboard.nextInt();
           }

           if (method3==1)
           {rungeKutta3();
           }
           if (method3==2)
           {euler3();
           }
           }     

      }

      public static void blanklines()
      {
         for (int l=0; l<11; l++)
         {
            System.out.println();
           }
       }

      public static void demenu()
      {
         System.out.println("1. y'=(x+1)^2\n" + 
                          "2. y'=3(x^2)*(y-4)^2\n" +
                          "3. y'=3(x^2)*(y-2)^2");
         System.out.print("Please enter the number of which \ndifferential equation you want to use:  ");
        }

      public static void menu1()
      {

         System.out.print("\n1. Runge Kutta\n" + 
                          "2. Euler\n");
         System.out.print("Please enter the number of which \nmethod you want to use:  ");                
         }

      public static void menu2()
      {
         System.out.print("\n1. Runge Kutta\n" + 
                          "2. Euler\n");
         System.out.print("Please enter the number of which \nmethod you want to use:  ");                
         }

         public static void menu3()
      {
         System.out.print("\n1. Runge Kutta\n" + 
                          "2. Euler\n");
         System.out.print("Please enter the number of which \nmethod you want to use:  ");                
         }


      public static void rungeKutta1() throws IOException
      {
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

         double y;
         double h;
         double x;
         double i;


         System.out.print("\nPlease enter an initial y value:  ");
         y = keyboard.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Please enter an initial x value:  ");
         x = keyboard.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Please enter a h value:  ");
         h = keyboard.nextDouble();
         if (h<=0)
            {
               System.out.println("\nEnter a valid h value");
               System.out.print("Please enter a h value:  ");
         h = keyboard.nextDouble();
         }

         System.out.print("Please enter the amount of results that you want:  ");
         i = keyboard.nextInt();
         if (i<1)
            {
               System.out.println("\nPlease enter an amount of 1 or greater");
               System.out.print("Please enter the amount of results that you want:  ");
         i = keyboard.nextInt();
            }

         System.out.println();

         System.out.print("Your results will be printed\n"
                             + "to a file. Please enter a name\n"
                             + "for the file:   ");
         String filename = keyboard.next();

         System.out.println();

         System.out.println("x values\t" + "y values");
         System.out.println("___________________________");

         double K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K9, K10;

         File file = new File(filename);

         PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);

         for (int number=1; number<=i; number++)
            {
            System.out.printf("When x = %.2f\t", x);
            System.out.printf("y = %.4f\n", y);
            outputFile.printf("When x = %.2f\t" + "y = %.4f", x,y);
               outputFile.println();
               K1 = Math.pow(x+1, 2);
               K2 = x+h/2;
               K3 = y+(h/2)*K1;
               K4 = Math.pow(K2+1, 2);
               K5 = y+(h/2)*K2;
               K6 = Math.pow(K2+1, 2);
               K7 = x+h;
               K8 = y+h*K6;
               K9 = Math.pow(K7+1, 2);
               K10 = y+h/6*(K1+2*(K4+K6)+K9);

               x = x+h;

               y = K10;

               }
               outputFile.close();
              }



       public static void euler1()throws IOException
       {
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

         double y;
         double h;
         double x;
         double i;

         System.out.print("\nPlease enter an initial y value:  ");
         y = keyboard.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Please enter an initial x value:  ");
         x = keyboard.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Please enter a h value:  ");
         h = keyboard.nextDouble();
         if (h<=0)
            {
               System.out.println("\nEnter a valid h value");
               System.out.print("Please enter a h value:  ");
         h = keyboard.nextDouble();
         }


         System.out.print("Please enter the amount of results that you want:  ");
         i = keyboard.nextInt();
         if (i<1)
            {
               System.out.println("\nPlease enter an amount of 1 or greater");
               System.out.print("Please enter the amount of results that you want:  ");
         i = keyboard.nextInt();
            }

         System.out.println();

         System.out.print("Your results will be printed\n"
                             + "to a file. Please enter a name\n"
                             + "for the file:   ");
         String filename = keyboard.next();

         System.out.println();

         System.out.println("x values\t" + "y values");
         System.out.println("___________________________");

         double E1, E2, E3, E4, E5;

          File file = new File(filename);

         PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);


        for (int number=1; number<=i; number++)
        {   
            System.out.printf("While x = %.2f\t", x); 
            System.out.printf("y = %.4f\n", y);
            outputFile.printf("When x = %.2f\t" + "y = %.4f", x,y);
               outputFile.println();

            E1 = Math.pow(x+1, 2);

            E2 = x+h;

            E3 = y+(h*E1);

            E4 = Math.pow(E2+1, 2);

            E5 = y+h/2*(E1+E4);

            x = x+h;

            y = E5;

          }
          outputFile.close();
          }



          public static void rungeKutta2() throws IOException
          {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

         double y;
         double h;
         double x;
         int i;

         System.out.print("\nPlease enter an initial y value:  ");
         y = keyboard.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Please enter an initial x value:  ");
         x = keyboard.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Please enter a h value:  ");
         h = keyboard.nextDouble();
         if (h<=0)
            {
               System.out.println("\nEnter a valid h value");
               System.out.print("Please enter a h value:  ");
         h = keyboard.nextDouble();
         }


         System.out.print("Please enter the amount of results that you want:  ");
         i = keyboard.nextInt();
         if (i<1)
            {
               System.out.println("\nPlease enter an amount of 1 or greater");
               System.out.print("Please enter the amount of results that you want:  ");
         i = keyboard.nextInt();
            }

         System.out.println();

         System.out.print("Your results will be printed\n"
                             + "to a file. Please enter a name\n"
                             + "for the file:   ");
         String filename = keyboard.next();

         System.out.println();

         System.out.println("x values\t" + "y values");
         System.out.println("___________________________");

         double R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10;

         File file = new File(filename);

         PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);

         for (int number=1; number<=i; number++)
            {
               System.out.printf("While x = %.2f\t", x); 
            System.out.printf("y = %.4f\n", y);
            outputFile.printf("When x = %.2f\t" + "y = %.4f", x,y);
               outputFile.println();

               R1 = 3*(x*x)*Math.pow((y-4), 2);

               R2 = x+h/2;

               R3 = y+(h/2)*R1;

               R4 = (3*(R2*R2))*Math.pow(R3-4, 2);

               R5 = y+(h/2)*R4;

               R6 = (3*(R2*R2))*Math.pow(R5-4, 2);

               R7 = x+h;

               R8 = y+h*R6;

               R9 = (3*(R7*R7))*Math.pow(R8-4, 2);

               R10 = y+h/6*(R1+2*(R4+R6)+R9);


               x = x+h;

               y = R10;
               }
               outputFile.close();
            }



          public static void euler2()
          {
            int i;
            double y;
            double h;
            double x;

         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.print("\nPlease enter an initial y value:  ");
         y = keyboard.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Please enter an initial x value:  ");
         x = keyboard.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Please enter a h value:  ");
         h = keyboard.nextDouble();
         if (h<=0)
            {
               System.out.println("\nEnter a valid h value");
               System.out.print("Please enter a h value:  ");
         h = keyboard.nextDouble();
         }


         System.out.print("Please enter the amount of results that you want:  ");
         i = keyboard.nextInt();
         if (i<1)
            {
               System.out.println("\nPlease enter an amount of 1 or greater");
               System.out.print("Please enter the amount of results that you want:  ");
         i = keyboard.nextInt();
            }

         System.out.println();

         System.out.print("Your results will be printed\n"
                             + "to a file. Please enter a name\n"
                             + "for the file:   ");
         String filename = keyboard.next();

         System.out.println();

         System.out.println("x values\t" + "y values");
         System.out.println("___________________________");


            double E1, E2, E3, E4, E5;

            File file = new File(filename);

         PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);

             for (int number=0; number<=i; number++)
                {
                System.out.printf("While x = %.2f\t", x); 
            System.out.printf("y = %.4f\n", y);
            outputFile.printf("When x = %.2f\t" + "y = %.4f", x,y);
               outputFile.println();

                E1 = 3*(x*x)*Math.pow((y-4), 2);

                E2 = x+h;

                E3 = y+h*E1;

                E4 = (3*(E2*E2))*Math.pow((E3-4), 2);

                E5 = y+h/2*(E1+E4);

                x = x+h; 

               y = E5;
                }
                outputFile.close();
            }



             public static void rungeKutta3()
          {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

         double y;
         double h;
         double x;
         int i;

         System.out.print("\nPlease enter an initial y value:  ");
         y = keyboard.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Please enter an initial x value:  ");
         x = keyboard.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Please enter a h value:  ");
         h = keyboard.nextDouble();
         if (h<=0)
            {
               System.out.println("\nEnter a valid h value");
               System.out.print("Please enter a h value:  ");
         h = keyboard.nextDouble();
         }


         System.out.print("Please enter the amount of results that you want:  ");
         i = keyboard.nextInt();
         if (i<1)
            {
               System.out.println("\nPlease enter an amount of 1 or greater");
               System.out.print("Please enter the amount of results that you want:  ");
         i = keyboard.nextInt();
            }

         System.out.println();

         System.out.print("Your results will be printed\n"
                             + "to a file. Please enter a name\n"
                             + "for the file:   ");
         String filename = keyboard.next();

         System.out.println();

         System.out.println("x values\t" + "y values");
         System.out.println("___________________________");

         double R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10;

         File file = new File(filename);

         PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);

         for (int number=1; number<=i; number++)
            {
               System.out.printf("While x = %.2f\t", x); 
            System.out.printf("y = %.4f\n", y);
            outputFile.printf("When x = %.2f\t" + "y = %.4f", x,y);
               outputFile.println();

               R1 = 3*(x*x)*Math.pow((y-2), 2);

               R2 = x+h/2;

               R3 = y+(h/2)*R1;

               R4 = (3*(R2*R2))*Math.pow(R3-2, 2);

               R5 = y+(h/2)*R4;

               R6 = (3*(R2*R2))*Math.pow(R5-2, 2);

               R7 = x+h;

               R8 = y+h*R6;

               R9 = (3*(R7*R7))*Math.pow(R8-2, 2);

               R10 = y+h/6*(R1+2*(R4+R6)+R9);


               x = x+h;

               y = R10;
               }
               outputFile.close();
            }



             public static void euler3()
          {
            int i;
            double y;
            double h;
            double x;

         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.print("\nPlease enter an initial y value:  ");
         y = keyboard.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Please enter an initial x value:  ");
         x = keyboard.nextDouble();

         System.out.print("Please enter a h value:  ");
         h = keyboard.nextDouble();
         if (h<=0)
            {
               System.out.println("\nEnter a valid h value");
               System.out.print("Please enter a h value:  ");
         h = keyboard.nextDouble();
         }


         System.out.print("Please enter the amount of results that you want:  ");
         i = keyboard.nextInt();
         if (i<1)
            {
               System.out.println("\nPlease enter an amount of 1 or greater");
               System.out.print("Please enter the amount of results that you want:  ");
         i = keyboard.nextInt();
            }

         System.out.println();

         System.out.print("Your results will be printed\n"
                             + "to a file. Please enter a name\n"
                             + "for the file:   ");
         String filename = keyboard.next();

         System.out.println();

         System.out.println("x values\t" + "y values");
         System.out.println("___________________________");


            double E1, E2, E3, E4, E5;

            File file = new File(filename);

         PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);

             for (int number=0; number<=i; number++)
                {
                System.out.printf("While x = %.2f\t", x); 
            System.out.printf("y = %.4f\n", y);
            outputFile.printf("When x = %.2f\t" + "y = %.4f", x,y);
               outputFile.println();

                E1 = 3*(x*x)*Math.pow((y-2), 2);

                E2 = x+h;

                E3 = y+h*E1;

                E4 = (3*(E2*E2))*Math.pow((E3-2), 2);

                E5 = y+h/2*(E1+E4);

                x = x+h;

               y = E5;
                }
               outputFile.close(); 
            }


          }
```

Comment: I suggest you read the error message and follow the suggestion provided.  What is your doubt?

Comment: That's a lot of code to dig through.... Maybe you can narrow down it down to the areas you think are causing your errors.

Answer (score 1):

On this method

```
public static void euler1()throws IOException
```

you declare that this method might throw an IOException like FileNotFoundException.

You have to do this in every method this might happen including.

```
public static void euler2()
{
```

I strongly suggest you use an IDE to

- help you format your code.
- refactor the class so there is not so many unrelated methods in it.
- add these exceptions for you as you type.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I can't believe I missed something that simple. And you are right I just don't understand a lot of the concepts in java as I am just in the beginer course.

Comment: @T.B. this is where using an IDE with auto-fixes can help ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that euler2(), euler3() and rungeKutta3() neither catch nor declare FileNotFoundException (or it's superclass IOException) to be thrown. So you can either wrap the respective code in there in try-catch-blocks or for simplicity just declare IOExceptions to be thrown on those 2 methods:

`public static void euler2() throws IOException {
[...]
}`

`public static void euler3() throws IOException {
[...]
}`

`public static void rungeKutta3() throws IOException {
[...]
}`

Throwing FileNotFoundException in your main method as suggested in another answer has no effect as those have to be caught by the 3 methods already. Besides, FileNotFoundException is an IOException, so that was already covered.

Answer (score 0):

```
rungeKutta1()
euler1()
rungeKutta2()
euler2()
rungeKutta3()
euler3()
```

these are the methods that i noticed throwing the filenotfound exception
since these methods use this specific line

`PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(filename);`

you can change the methods to 
`rungeKutta1()throws Exception` 
or
you can embed the code inside every method to handle the exception like this

```
try{
//your code inside the methods
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("exeption");
}
```